# How to add https support in Global Sensor Networks(GSN)

Tags: java, open-source, cloud, sensors, iot

Now am work with global sensor network(GSN & X-GSN). how to enable https (SSL) support in GSN or X-GSN . anybody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable it in the config:

[Link to Config file](https://github.com/LSIR/gsn/blob/master/conf/gsn.xml)

Comment: thanks for u r comment. its working fine